# apache sshd public key authentication

Tags: java, authorization, public-key, sshd, mina

I am trying to set up an ssh server using apache mina sshd. I want to use  public key authentication, and basically I want to know how to implement

```
package org.apache.sshd.server;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSession;

public interface PublickeyAuthenticator {

boolean authenticate(String username, PublicKey key, ServerSession session);

}
```

I see that what is passed is another public key. So I assume that you are supposed to compare the public key given in the param with the public key that the server has. But I don't know how to do that.

One thing I have found is [this](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/xref/org/apache/maven/wagon/providers/ssh/TestPublickeyAuthenticator.html) implementation. which seems pointless, as it seems to compare the modulus of the public key to itself. Assuming that this implementation has a bug, and should be comparing the moduli of each public key, is this enough for authentication - that the moduli agree? Surely if I just fed my publicly available public key to this function, then I would get authenticated?

Answer (score 8):

I think I found the answer in the source of `org.apache.sshd.server.auth.UserAuthPublicKey#auth`. This class does the actual auth with the key. I think what confused me is the name of the method - `authenticate()`. What really happens is as follows:

- The server asks for the public key of the client
- The public key is passed to `PublickeyAuthenticator#authenticate`
- All you are supposed to do in `authenticate()` is check that this is a public key that you want to allow
- If `authenticate()` returns true, then `UserAuthPublicKey#auth` will check that a message has been signed with the private key. If it has then authentication has been validated.

Answer (score 1):

The below code is an example of how to perform Public Key Authentication using Apache MINA SSHD, the example code creates a SFTP server.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;

@Service
public class MySftpServer {

    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MySftpServer.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void startServer() throws IOException {
        start();
    }

    private void start() throws IOException {
        SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
        sshd.setHost("localhost");
        sshd.setPort(2222);
        sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(new File("host.ser")));
        sshd.setSubsystemFactories(Collections.singletonList(new SftpSubsystemFactory()));
        sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator((username, password, session) -> username.equals("test") && password.equals("password"));
        sshd.setPublickeyAuthenticator(new AuthorizedKeysAuthenticator(new File("<Location of authorized_keys file>")));
        sshd.start();
        log.info("SFTP server started");
    }
}
```

Similar to what @northshorefiend mentioned in his answer, in this case `AuthorizedKeysAuthenticator` takes the public key passed to the server and validates it against the authorized_keys file `new AuthorizedKeysAuthenticator(new File("<Location of authorized_keys file>")` . If the specified public key exists in the file, then it passes the authentication.

You can read more details about this [here](https://programmingtechie.com/2019/08/18/how-to-implement-an-sftp-server-in-java-spring-boot-using-apache-mina-sshd-part-2-using-public-key-authentication/) and [here](https://programmingtechie.com/2019/02/23/how-to-implement-an-sftp-server-in-java-spring-boot-using-apache-mina-sshd/)

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but I keep getting this error:
test@localhost: Permission denied (keyboard-interactive,publickey).
What am I doing wrong?

This is how I try to connect:
$ sftp -oPort=2222 test@localhost
from the directory where my private key is